# Imports from a lerna shared package seem to require src at the end of the name (Typescript/javascript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, lerna

I have a simple lerna project like:

```
Project
 |    
 +-- packages
 |  |  
 |  +-- shared
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- src
 |  |       |  
 |  |       +-- index.ts
 |  |       +-- someDir   
 |  |
 |  +-- usesShared
 |
 +
```

My index.ts has entries like:

```
export * from "./someDir";
```

When I import a class from someDir in a "usesShared" class, I am having to put /src at the end of the import like:

```
import {GreatClass} from "myShared/src";
```

I am new to Typescript, javascript, & lerna but this seems wrong to me.  It seems like it should just be:

```
import {GreatClass} from "myShared";
```

Can someone point me towards how to fix this?  Does this have something to do with lerna or am I missing something in package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "shared" or "myShared" (not sure what you named it), create `index.ts`:

```
export * from "./src";
```

To import the class from `usesShared`:

```
import { GreatClass } from "../myShared";
```